# Unmarshal XML tag that contains mixed contents(e.g. CDATA, other tags)

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling, cdata

Try to unmarshal a xml file like:

```
<Element>
    <![CDATA[hello]]>
    <image>some_url_here</image>
    <![CDATA[world]]>
    mixed content here
</Element>
```

there are different types of data inside the Element tag, how can I unmashal this xml into a struct like:

```
type XMLElement struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Element"`
    CDatas []string `....`
    Image string `...`
    PlainText string `...`
}
```

or any other struct this xml could be unmarshalled in.

Comment: Use the tag `xml:",cdata"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a CDATA node of xml with go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191596/how-to-create-a-cdata-node-of-xml-with-go)

Comment: @SignatureD `CDatas` must be a `string` or `[]byte` and then use the `cdata` tag option as mentioned by Abdullah's comment. https://play.golang.org/p/uzNWL3mveQg

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your answer. But what if I want to unmarshal the xml into another struct like
```
type Children struct {
      GenericItems []string `xml:"..."`
}
```

the generic item can be the content of CDATA or the url of image or just the plain text. As these elements are put in an array called GenericItems, so we can keep their order in the result struct.

Comment: You can have your type implement the `encoding.TextUnmarshaler` interface, then your type will be called once with all the content that was present in the separate CDATA sections, which means you'll have to parse that yourself and then put it into the slice.

Comment: ... here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/iC83C2B4ORu

Comment: ... for decoding everything into a single list, not only cdata but also plain elements you'll have to implement the `xml.Unmarshaler` interface, it's a bit more involved compared to `TextUnmarshaler` but it's certainly doable, you can look for example code on github: https://github.com/search?q=language%3Ago+unmarshalxml&type=Code

Comment: @mkopriva I tried to implement the xml.Unmarshaler: https://play.golang.org/p/oDvEsltjyP6, but it seems the function just skip the cdata content. The first element I got in the unmarshaler is the Image element

Comment: This is because UnmarshalXML will always start with a valid xml element, so you need to implement it for the enclosing type and then loop over the decoder's tokens. I'll whip up an incomplete example, one sec.

Comment: ... here: https://play.golang.org/p/twDRMmExyjS

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks a lot ! I tried your sample today and find it works well except one problem. If there is head/tail spaces in the CDATA string, these spaces will be deleted because of the TrimSpace(), but if we don't call trimspace(), there should be a lot of unexpected '\n' in the result array. https://play.golang.org/p/C27j2JEaGtS

Comment: Use https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim instead and provide a cutset of only those whitespace characters that you want to get rid of. e.g. `"\n\r"`.

Comment: @mkopriva emm.. actually I need to ignore all the text outside the CDATA tag, but it seems I can't know that the current CHARDATA is inside or outside the CDATA tag from current code flow

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not so good, because [xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery) mades `CDATA` element as TEXT node type, but I considered it is easy and simple, it using `XPath` query.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/antchfx/xmlquery"
)

func main() {
    s := `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Element>
<![CDATA[hello]]>
<image>some_url_here</image>
<![CDATA[world]]>
</Element>
`
    doc, err := xmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    elem := xmlquery.FindOne(doc, "//Element")
    for n := elem.FirstChild; n != nil; n = n.NextSibling {
        if n.Data == "image" {
            fmt.Printf("image: %s\n", n.InnerText())
        } else if n.Type == xmlquery.TextNode {
            if len(strings.TrimSpace(n.InnerText())) == 0 {
                // skip it because its' empty node
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("cdata: %s\n", n.InnerText())
            }
        }
    }
    // or using query expression
    image := xmlquery.FindOne(doc, "//image")
    fmt.Printf("image: %s\n", image.InnerText())
}
```